Burp Suit - CORS vulnerabilities identified
While ruung the Burp-Suit for my web application, I am getting the below Cross-origin resource sharing Issue
Cross-origin resource sharing: arbitrary origin trusted
/plugins/angular-1.8.1/angular.min.js
Issue detail:
The application implements an HTML5 cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) policy for this request that
allows access from any domain.
The application allowed access from the requested origin null
Snip
The application allows two-way interaction from the null origin. This effectively means that any domain can
perform two-way interaction by causing the browser to submit the null origin, for example by issuing the
request from a sandboxed iframe.
Issue background:
An HTML5 cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) policy controls whether and how content running on other
domains can perform two-way interaction with the domain that publishes the policy. The policy is fine-grained
and can apply access controls per-request based on the URL and other features of the request.
Trusting arbitrary origins effectively disables the same-origin policy, allowing two-way interaction by thirdparty web sites. Unless the response consists only of unprotected public content, this policy is likely to
present a security risk.
If the site specifies the header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true, third-party sites may be able to carry
out privileged actions and retrieve sensitive information. Even if it does not, attackers may be able to bypass
any IP-based access controls by proxying through users' browsers.
This is very first time I am getting this error, I tried to google the Doubt but couldn't able to understand. It will be appreciate, If can provide insight or conclusion os this issue.

The server allows CORS from any origin. Is this expected?

@jabaa. The server currently permits any origin, although I believe it should be limited to the running server for security reasons.

Glad, I was able to clarify the problem. Anything else?

I haven't been able to determine where to specify allowing access from a specific origin. My setup involves HTML, JavaScript, AngularJS, and Java.

It's in the Java backend.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You've mentioned everything except for the part that matters when it comes to CORS headers: which java server/server framerwork you're using =)

I am using SpringBoot Framework.

You have to configure it in your Spring Boot configuration. You should be able to find dozens of questions and answers and hundreds of other articles on this topic.
